# For loop with two variables in R

Tags: r

I'm constructing a panel dataset, which is going well. I can't get over this problem where I want to create some variables out of another dataframe.

I'm pretty sure I need the for-loop but can't find the solution for this specific situation.

I have these two dataframes:

```
name <- c("apple", "apple", "apple", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange","orange")
day <- c(1,8,9,0,2,2,2,7)
score <- c(7,7,8,1,5,8,4,4)
df1 <- data.frame(name, day, score)
```

&

```
name1 <- c("apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange","orange", "orange", "orange", "orange","orange", "orange","orange")
day1 <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
volume_day <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
volume_day_cum <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
avg_score_day <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
avg_score_cum <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
var_day <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
var_cum <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
df2 <- data.frame(name1, day1, volume_day, volume_day_cum, avg_score_day, avg_score_cum, var_day, var_cum)
```

I have a panel dataset on name-day level. Therefore, the instances of df1, which are given scores per row, needs to be coded in df2 for matching name and day. If there is no match, the 0 can stay. I'm looking for the instances itself (volume), the average scores and variation per day and cumulatively for all three variables. The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
volume_day <- c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,3,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0)
volume_day_cum <- c(0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,1,1,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5)
avg_score_day <- c(0,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,8,0,1,0,5.66,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0)
avg_score_cum <- c(0,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7.33,7.33,1,1,4.5,4.5,4.5,4.5,4.5,4.4,4.4,4.4,4.4)
var_day <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2.88,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
var_cum <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.22,0.22,0,0,6.25,6.25,6.25,6.25,6.25,5.04,5.04,5.04,5.04)
resultdata <- data.frame(name1, day1, volume_day, volume_day_cum, avg_score_day, avg_score_cum, var_day, var_cum)
```

I'm relatively new to R and coding in general. If I have insufficiently described my issue just let me know. Hopefully someone can help me out here.

Comment: `'score_day' not found`, do you mean `avg_score_day`?

Comment: Please run your code and verify it works for you. I think your `df2` is using the wrong variable names, and `resultdata` has rows of different length (e.g., `name` length 8, most others length 22 ... perhaps `name1` and `day1`?)

Comment: Your `resultdata` is also inconsistent with your `df1`, namely `orange` day `0` has something in `df1` but is not counted in the results. Where did you come up with your `resultdata`?

Comment: You're right. I manually made the resultdata and made same mistakes there. Will run the code to verify my work in the future. It should all work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some inconsistencies between your `df1` and your `resultdata`, but here's a shot:

```r
library(dplyr)
# library(zoo)
df1 %>%
  group_by(name, day) %>%
  summarize(
    volume_day = as.numeric(n()),
    var_day = var(score),
    avg_score_day = mean(score),
    score = sum(score)
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  full_join(select(df2, name=name1, day=day1), by = c("name", "day")) %>%
  arrange(name, day) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(volume_day, score, avg_score_day, var_day), ~ if_else(is.na(.), 0, .)) %>%
  mutate(
    volume_day_cum = cumsum(volume_day),
    avg_score_cum = if_else(cumsum(score) == 0, 0, cumsum(score) / volume_day_cum),
    var_cum = zoo::rollapply(score, n(), var, partial = TRUE)
  ) %>%
  print(n=99)
# # A tibble: 22 x 9
# # Groups:   name [2]
#    name     day volume_day var_day avg_score_day score volume_day_cum avg_score_cum var_cum
#    <fct>  <dbl>      <dbl>   <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>          <dbl>         <dbl>   <dbl>
#  1 apple      0          0    0             0        0              0          0       8.17
#  2 apple      1          1    0             7        7              1          7       7   
#  3 apple      2          0    0             0        0              1          7       6.12
#  4 apple      3          0    0             0        0              1          7       9.53
#  5 apple      4          0    0             0        0              1          7      12.6 
#  6 apple      5          0    0             0        0              1          7      11.8 
#  7 apple      6          0    0             0        0              1          7      12.6 
#  8 apple      7          0    0             0        0              1          7      11   
#  9 apple      8          1    0             7        7              2          7      12.1 
# 10 apple      9          1    0             8        8              3          7.33   13.5 
# 11 apple     10          0    0             0        0              3          7.33   15.1 
# 12 orange     0          1    0             1        1              1          1      47.2 
# 13 orange     1          0    0             0        0              1          1      40.6 
# 14 orange     2          3    4.33          5.67    17              4          4.5    35.1 
# 15 orange     3          0    0             0        0              4          4.5    31.5 
# 16 orange     4          0    0             0        0              4          4.5    28.6 
# 17 orange     5          0    0             0        0              4          4.5    26.2 
# 18 orange     6          0    0             0        0              4          4.5    29.0 
# 19 orange     7          1    0             4        4              5          4.4    32   
# 20 orange     8          0    0             0        0              5          4.4     2   
# 21 orange     9          0    0             0        0              5          4.4     2.29
# 22 orange    10          0    0             0        0              5          4.4     2.67
```

Comment: Hi r2evans, thanks! This already helped me a lot into the right direction. Firstly, what I meant with var_cum is the variation over time. So right now there is a variation score per day (var_day) and I also need the variation of the scores on that given day and all the previous scores. Is there a way to mutate that? Secondly, the count ('score') is not needed. What I need for 'avg_score_day' is the average score on that day. Thus, apple on day 9 should be 8 as that is the only score given on that day and 5.66 for orange on day 2 as there are 3 scores (5, 8, 4).

Comment: *"score is not needed"* ... remove it? Giving you too many columns should not be a problem. Your variance is still wrong, `var(c(5,8,4))` is 4.3, not sure if that's just a typo. Your variation over time seems wrong, as soon as there is any non-zero value, `var_cum` should be non-zero. I'll put in my answer, but if the numbers are not what you think they should be, then either check *your* math or you need to better define why things are as they are.